# How to return Flux.just on status in webclient

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I have a question

how can return empty flux onStatus 5xx is it possible?

```
@Override
public Flux<Repository> getAllUserRepositories(User user) {
    return WebClient.create()
            .get()
            .uri(hostname + ":" + port + "/user" + "/repos" + "?access_token=" + ACCESS_TOKEN + "&type=private")
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, clientResponse -> Mono.error(new WebServerException("Problem with service", null)))
            .bodyToFlux(Repository.class)
            .filter(repository -> repository.getName().contains(user.getName()));
}
```

Comment: you can use `onErrorMap` to match for `predicate` and return empty `Flux`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `onErrorResume` as follows:

```
return WebClient.create()
    .get()
    .uri(hostname + ":" + port + "/user" + "/repos" + "?access_token=" + ACCESS_TOKEN + "&type=private")
    .retrieve()
    .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, clientResponse -> Mono.error(new WebServerException("Problem with service", null)))
    .bodyToFlux(Repository.class)
    .onErrorResume(WebServerException.class, (e) -> Flux.empty())
    .filter(repository -> repository.getName().contains(user.getName()));
```